# How to access nth dimension in a numpy array)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array of the shape `(m,o,n)`. I want to access the `n`th component (third dimensions) and reduce it - say `n = 4`, I only want to take the first three values.
I tried `array[][][:3]` but this gives me errors since I cannot the other two `[]` empty.

Comment: how about `array[:,:,:3]`, or even smaller `array[...,:3]`

Comment: Yes I just tried that and it works! I did not know I need to put them in the same brackets! Thanks!